# Secure serial port for particular python application

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, driver

I have a python application("App1") that uses serial port `/dev/ttyUSB0`. This application is running as Linux service. It is running very well as it is perfectly automated for the task that I need it to perform. However, I have recently came to realize that sometimes I accidentally use the same serial port for another python application that I am developing which causes unwanted interference with "App1".

I did try to lock down "App1" as follows:

```
ser=serial.Serial(PORT, BAUDRATE)
fcntl.lockf(ser, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
```

However, for other applications I sometimes unknowingly using

```
ser=serial.Serial(PORT, BAUDRATE)
```

without checking for `ser.isOpen()`

In order to prevent this I was wondering during the times I work on other applications, is there a way for `ser=serial.Serial(PORT, BAUDRATE)` to notify me that the serial port is already in use when I try to access it?

A solution I came up with is to create a `cronjob` that runs forever which essentially checks the following:

```
fuser -k /dev/ttyUSB0 #to get the PID of activated services that uses /dev/ttyUSB0
pkill -f <PID of second application shown in output above> #kill the application belonging to the second PID given by the above command
```

The above would ensure that whenever two applications use the same serial port, the second PID will get killed(I am aware there are some leaks in this logic). What do you guys think? If this is not a good solution, is there any way for `ser=serial.Serial(PORT, BAUDRATE)` to notify me that `/dev/ttyUSB0` is already in use when I try to access it or do I need to implement the logic at driver level? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I'd be tempted to go down the route of `inotifywait -m /dev/ttyUSB0`, capture relevant events in a loop and act upon those, rather than using `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpler thing to do there is to create a different user for the "stable process", and use plain file permissions to give that user exclusive access to  `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

With Unix groups and still plain permissions, that other process can still access any other resource it needs that would be under your main user - so it should be plain simple

If you are not aware of them, check the documentation for the commands `chown` and `chmod`.

Comment: Tried this, over time I've grown uncomfortable with assigning permissions. I am currently looking into cross-process mutex for Python. What do you think about it?